# Count Unique Values, Return object array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I have searched high and low how to do this via unique count distinct groupby etc on stack overflow on this particular query with no luck.

I have a database scheme of

```
______________
|____TYPE_____|
|____repair___|
|___service___|
|___repair____|
|___repair____|
|___coating___|
|___service___|
|___service___|
|__coating____|
|_maintenance_|
|___repair____|
|___coating___|
```

What I am trying to return is the total count per unique "type" in the database.

```
private function getOpportunities() {
   return OpportunityTypes::distinct()->select('type')->groupBy('type')->get();
}
```

foreach type return the following in an object array.

```
    array('type' => 'Repair', 'count' => 4),
...
```

Repair - 4
Service - 3
Coating - 3
Maintenance - 1

I will be passing the returned results into a blade template and running a foreach loop to display all the opportunity types that are recorded in the database and have a sum total of each said type.

Blade Template

```
            @foreach ($opportunities['opportunitytypes'] as $opportunity)
                {{ $opportunity['type'] }} - {{ $opportunity['total'] }}
            @endforeach
```

Result

Coating System - 1

```
                                    Dead Valley - 1
                                    Emergency Tarp - 1
                                    Gutter Replacement - 1
                                    Maintenance - 1
                                    New Construction - 1
                                    Other - 1
                                    Replacement - 1
```

Code

```
private function getOpportunities() {
        return OpportunityTypes::select('type', DB::raw('count(type) as total'))->groupBy('type')->get();
    }
```

Comment: @Mohammad https://ibb.co/hGyPaU using `OpportunityTypes::select('type', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('type')->get();`

Comment: Same results with the `select('type', DB::raw('count(type) as total'))->groupBy('type')->get();`

Comment: @Mohammad did you see my replies?